# How to get Driver Name?

Tags: c++, driver

how can I get the driver's name of a device to use with `CreateFile`?

```
handle = CreateFile( DRIVER_NAME_HERE,  
                     GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                     FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                     NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's depend on what you want. A typical examples are

```
\\.\C:
\\.\Tcp
\\.\PhysicalDrive0
\\?\usbstor#disk&ven_sandisk&prod_cruzer&rev_8.01#1740030578903736&0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
\\.\CON
```

(see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx). I recommend you to also to use WinObj (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657.aspx) to understand more about which devices you can use. If you start WinObj.exe and choose `GLOBAL??` namespace you will see different names which can you use after `\\.\` prefix. The function `QueryDosDevice` can be also helpful.

You can use `DefineDosDevice` function to create additional Symbolic link from `\Device\Blabla` to a name which you can use in `CreateFile` with the syntax `\\.\MyLogicalDevicName` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364014(VS.85).aspx).

If you want to send IOCTL codes with respect of `DeviceIoControl` function to a device, you should use 0 instead of `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE` as the second parameter of `CreateFile` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363147(v=VS.85).aspx)